# How to continue playing music when I killed App

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In Android,I use Service and BroadcastReceiver to play music.

The MediaPlayer can continue playing music when I press Home Button or Back Button.**But it can not works when I removed it from Overview Screen.** Even If I set the Service as Foreground Service.

**@0xDEADC0DE points out that the id shouldn't be 0.** I modify it and now it can work well.But it must have a notification.Some Apps such like NetEase Cloud Music,which hasn't any notification and can play even if it be killed,how it works?

**update:**
I found that I have closed that app's notification,so it seems still playing music without notification when I kill it....So the problem resolved,thanks

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java** ,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageButton mPlayButton;
private ImageButton mPreviousButton;
private ImageButton mNextButton;
private TextView mMusicName;
private boolean mState = false;
private Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMusicName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.music_name);
    mPlayButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    mPreviousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);

    startService(intent);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.play:
            if (!mState) {
                //start
                mState = true;
                mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.geekband.mo.musicplayer");
                intent.putExtra("action", 0);
                sendBroadcast(intent);

            } else {
                //pause
                mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_play_circle_outline_white_48dp);
                mState = false;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.geekband.mo.musicplayer");
                intent.putExtra("action", 1);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.next:
            mState = true;
            mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.geekband.mo.musicplayer");
            intent.putExtra("action", 2);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.previous:
            mState = true;
            mPlayButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_48dp);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            intent2.setAction("com.geekband.mo.musicplayer");
            intent2.putExtra("action", 3);
            sendBroadcast(intent2);
            break;

    }
    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
        stopService(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**Service.java** ,

```
public class MusicService extends Service {


private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private MusicBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.d("MusicService", "onTaskRemoved");
}

private void pause() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
}

private void previous() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MusicService.this, R.raw.loststars);
    mPlayer.start();
}

private void next() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MusicService.this, R.raw.nanshannan);
    mPlayer.start();
}

private void start() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mBroadcastReceiver = new MusicBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.geekband.mo.musicplayer");
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MusicService.this, R.raw.loststars);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MusicService.this)
            .setContentTitle("play")
            .setContentText("playing")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();
    // manager.notify(0, noti);
    // startForeground(0, noti);
    startForeground(1, noti);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public class MusicBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int action = intent.getIntExtra("action",0);
        switch (action) {
            case 0:
                start();
                break;

            case 1:
                pause();
                break;

            case 2:
                next();
                break;

            case 3:
                previous();
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't play music through a force close of your app.. Swiping an app away from the task switcher is different than a force close. The system will attempt to finish all activities and will call onTaskRemoved for any services running..  You should implement onTaskRemoved and not have it kill your service..

Comment: I override onTaskRemoved and it indeed be called when I swip the app.But it not works,the music stopped.

Comment: Try putting startForeground in onStartCommand rather than onCreate(). Also I don' thtink you need to call notify() with the notifcation..

Comment: The notification still exists even if i did not call notify().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service gets killed just like all other resources of your app if you remove it from the task switcher or when you kill the app. By killing/removing it from the task switcher, the process is stopped. Your service lives in that same process and is therefore also stopped. This is simply how Android (and other operating systems) works.

**EDIT**
This is indeed possible, but according to the documentation, you should not use `startForeground` with an ID of 0:

> Caution: The integer ID you give to startForeground() must not be 0.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: But other MusicPlayers can still play even if it had been removed,how they can do this?

Comment: Well I tried it with the default music player on a Sony Xperia Z3 and when I remove the app from the task switcher, the music stops immediately. I don't know how other apps do it, if it is even possible. It might be that they are restarted due a broadcast or something like that

Comment: I'm using a music app named netease cloud music,it can still work when i kill it..

Comment: I looked into the documentation of `startForeground`. It looks like you are right and it is possible, but the documentation states that you must not use 0 as ID:
Caution: The integer ID you give to startForeground() must not be 0 (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). So I suggest using a different ID and according to the documentation it should work

Comment: Well,it indeed should not be 0. But it must have a notification.That App hasn't any notification and it still can do this,why?

Comment: I think it may be a random number which is unique for your app. I'm not sure if it has to be a number that you also supply to the NotificationManager. I suggest you read the link, I think you find more there

Comment: I found that I have closed that app's notification,so it seems still playing music without notification when I kill it....  :(